# Undefined function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, private-functions

I using the function dtw in the latest MATLAB release, and would like to tweak a few parts of it. To get started, I typed:

```
edit dtw
```

I saved the resulting code to file called dtw_Copy.m, and changed the name of the function to `dtw_Copy` as well. Going through the code line by line with a set of input parameters `x` and `y`, around line 90:

```
[metric, varargin] = getmutexclopt({'absolute','euclidean','squared','symmkl'},'euclidean',varargin);
```

I receive an error message:

> Undefined function 'getmutexclopt' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

I also get this error message if I do not go through the code line by line, and simply type `dtw_Current(x,y)`, after again testing a set of input parameters `x` and `y`.

Upon running:

```
help 'getmutexclopt'
```

it is indicated that `getmutexclopt` is not found. I tried also:

```
edit 'getmutexclopt'
```

But am told that currentDirectory/getmutexcloptm.m does not exist.

I tried:

```
which getmutexclopt
```

And am told that `getmutexclopt` is not found.

Searching online, I found [a resource that seemed straight-forward](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-functions.html) in trouble-shooting this error.  The resource recommends to ensure the toolbox is installed. I am unsure which toolbox supports the function `getmutexclopt`, and so I type the function name into the [website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/). This results in a message that: "Your search - getmutexclopt - did not match any documents."

The resource also recommends verifying the path used to access the function. I followed the instructions to do so, and when I typed:

```
which -all getmutexclopt
```

I receive:

```
currentDirectory\matlab\toolbox\signal\signal\private\getmutexclopt.m  % Private to signal
```

This seems to indicate that the function is in the signal toolbox, which is private? Is there a possibility to still run `dtw_Current(x,y)` and/or to run its contents line by line?

Comment: Where have you saved `dtw_Current`?  [Private functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) are available only to functions in the folder immediately above the private subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this issue is because the function `getmutexclopt` is a [private function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html). You'll need to make a copy of that function if you hope to safely call it from your copy of `dtw`. It appears to be a basic function (type `edit private/getmutexclopt.m` in your Command Window) so you may be able to add it as a sub-function to your `dtw_Copy`/`dtw_Current`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19680611/2278029) – adding private functions to the search path is not allowed.